# Add some styling on last-child

Tags: html, css

I am trying to find last-child on the basic of class and wants to apply some styling but using :last-child selector its not as per expectation. I have a limitation I don't want to use java script and due the elements length is not fixed I can not use nth selector.

Used HTML Markup

```
<ul>
    <li class="a">First</li>
    <li class="a">Second</li>
    <li class="a">Third</li>    
    <li class="b">First</li>
    <li class="b">Second</li>
    <li class="b">Third</li>    
    <li class="c">First</li>
    <li class="c">Second</li>
    <li class="c">Third</li>        
</ul>
```

Used Css

```
.a{
    color:red;
}
.b{
    color:blue;
}
.c{
    color:green;
}

.a:last-child{
    color:green;
}
.b:last-child{
    color:red;
}
.c:last-child{
    color:blue;
}
```

Any help to how to approach this problem.

Comment: `a:last-child` is missing the leading `.` class selector. Same for the others. Is that a typo?

Comment: I think the OP is asking to apply style to the last child of each class.

Comment: please check the demo which i have created - http://jsfiddle.net/WanzY/1/ - Its only getting applied on class c

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to target last-child of ul element, than this is enough

```
ul li:last-child {

}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7wwP/)

Or if you want to style last child of each unique class than you need than `last-child` won't work here, you need to use `nth-of-type` instead or a formula like

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7wwP/4/)

```
ul li:nth-child(3n+3) { /* This way you don't have to use classes too */
    color: red;
}
```

> Note: If you are generating elements dynamically than as of now
>   there's no way to select last-child of element with a unique class. SO
>   you have to use `nth-child`, `nth-of-type` or a formula like I
>   mentioned

---

Other way you can do this is, programatically create an `ul` element after `n` iteration and in your loop and use [**this selector**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7wwP/5/)

Comment: I think the OP wanted the second option.

Comment: Want to apply some style on every third element. Not only on last element. please check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/WanzY/1/

Comment: Cant use ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
    color: red;
} because the element is not fixed

Comment: @saorabh I think `last-of-type` should work here, wait I'll work on that

Comment: @Mr.Alien I tried with last-of-type but no luck with css. :(

Comment: @saorabh There's no way you can achieve this in your way, I've provided you few demo and that way it should work

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're missing the point in front of your classnames, but anyway this wouldn't solve your problem. As you seem to generate your list programmatically , I would suggest adding a class to each last item with a certain class. Or alternatively use Javascript, which you don't want to...

Comment: `+1` yes, it is not possible with just CSS. This is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it will be easier to add some additional class to specify the last element or by using JS.

For instance, you may do something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="a ">First</li>
    <li class="a ">Second</li>
    <li class="a last">Third</li>    
    <li class="b">First</li>
    <li class="b">Second</li>
    <li class="b last">Third</li>    
    <li class="c">First</li>
    <li class="c">Second</li>
    <li class="c last">Third</li>        
</ul>
```

And css:

```
.a{
    color:red;
}
.b{
    color:blue;
}
.c{
    color:green;
}

.a.last{
    color:green;
}

.b.last{
    color:red;
}

.c.last{
    color:blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ud8KZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

you are not using dot in last three css class

```
.a:last-child{
    color:green;
}
.b:last-child{
    color:red;
}
.c:last-child{
    color:blue;
}
```

I think that's why you are not getting output